# PHP incoming webhook handling

Tags: php, wordpress, webhooks

I have a 3rd party website that has webhooks that send to a specific url. I set it up to send to a blank page on my site (example: www.mysite.com/webhook.php)

I have a var_dump set up in the webhook.php that should display any information in the post or get.. I am new to webhooks and might just not understand how they work. I assume that i can have `var_dump($_POST)` in my php file to display an array of the HTTP request that is coming to my site.

I cannot see any requests on my site from the hook after sending test data.. any ideas?

Comment: The `var_dump()` is returned to the site performing the webhook. Instead, you probably want to write the contents of `$_POST` (and/or `$_GET`) to a file so you can see what came in afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this to test the webhook.

```
<?php 
$fWrite = fopen("log.txt","a");
$wrote = fwrite($fWrite, var_dump($_POST));
fclose($fWrite);
?>
```

This will return var_dump data in `log.txt` file, since as rickdenhaan said 36 mins ago, your current `webhook.php` return data to the webhook not your view.

You may need to create log.txt manually if you don't have right on directory (755)

I'm currently working with a payment API that use webhook. Webhook send data to X url then do action and return code to webhook. so webhook.php is the place where my order if ispaid or not is proceed or not... here what I did:

```
if ($payment->isPaid() == TRUE)
{
    /*
     * At this point you'd probably want to start the process of delivering the product to the customer.
     */
    $con->query("UPDATE orders SET bankno = '$bankno', status = 'paid' WHERE ordertr = '$ids'");


}
elseif ($payment->isOpen() == FALSE)
{
    /*
     * The payment isn't paid and isn't open anymore. We can assume it was aborted.
     */
    $con->query("UPDATE orders SET bankno = '$bankno', status = 'closed' WHERE ordertr = '$ids'");

}
```

So if order paid mark as paid in database if not mark as closed. This show webhook usage. Doing action according to what the webhook data send.

Comment: I tried adding the above code to test and I am getting an empty array back.. is it possible that it wouldnt be putting it in the $_POST? I am using a requestb.in with an identical webhook to test and it is showing up there just fine.

Comment: Can you send me url of the API/webhook?

Comment: What's the data it should sent?

Comment: sorry fro delay, try to upload full code of the webhook and link to documentation of this webhook so I can check if it really send POST to x file. If you have some kind of panel to see debug, you may see if webhook data really sent to correct destination

Answer (score 2):

here is how i get content sent to my app:

`$varname = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

well my content are JSON encoded, but I think this would be fine:

`$varname = file_get_contents('php://input');`